# Can I use LockFileEx() with FILE_APPEND_DATA in CreateFileW()?

Tags: c++, winapi

This is the code working fine with `GENERIC_WRITE`, but I want to use `FILE_APPEND_DATA`:

```
hFile = CreateFileW(fname, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
OVERLAPPED sOverlapped;
sOverlapped.Offset = 50 * 3;
sOverlapped.OffsetHigh = 0;
fSuccess = LockFileEx(hFile, LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK | LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY, 0, dwBytesToWrite, 0, &sOverlapped);
```

When I use `FILE_APPEND_DATA` instead of `GENERIC_WRITE`, the `LockFileEx()` function does not lock the file.

Comment: [The documentation for `LockFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex) specifically states: "The handle must have been created with either the `GENERIC_READ` or `GENERIC_WRITE` access right."

Comment: Is there any another option to append the file with filelock?

Comment: Just seek to the end with `SetFilePointer`, then `WriteFile`.

Comment: you can use `FILE_READ_DATA|FILE_APPEND_DATA` combination. this will be work. despite i doubt that use LockFile api exist sense

Comment: @IgorTandetnik as generic note `SetFilePointer` senseless call. need simply pass offset to write inside `OVERLAPPED`. if we need use offset